# Molar conductivity of a strong electrolyte

Tags: physical-chemistry, reference-request

In 1910, Kohlrausch showed that the dependence of the molar conductivity of strong electrolytes is well described by the following equation:
$$\Lambda_m = \Lambda_m^\circ-K\sqrt{c}$$

This equation, known as Kohlrausch's law, states that the molar conductivity of strong electrolytes decreases with the square root of the concentration, with slope given by the quantity K (Kohlrausch's parameter). It is also found that this slope of the stoichiometry of the electrolyte.

I need to find for a paper the slope value for magnesium chloride, MgCl2, and the molar conductivity for different concentrations. But, I can't find this experimental data anywhere. I hope you can help me.